# Does cellular homology depend on CW structure?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a CW-space and $(E,\Phi),(E',\Phi')$ be CW-structures on $X$.

Then, does cellular homology depend on the choice of these CW-structures?

What is the reason for defining CW-complex as a space $X$ together with a specified CW-structure $(E,\Phi')$? Is it the same as calling a space 'metric space' when a specific metric is given, and 'metrizable space' when a specific metric is not given?

I'm pretty sure that cellular homology does not depend on the charateristic maps $\Phi$, but I'm not sure whether it would not depend on $E$.

Comment: Cellular homology is isomorphic to singular homology, which depends only on the homotopy type of the space you're considering. Look at Hatcher.

Answer (score 1):

As Pedro has said in a comment, cellular hoomology is isomorphic to singular homology, which depends only on the homotopy type, and therefore does not depend on the cellular structure you are considering for your space.

Regarding your question on the definition of CW-complex, there are at least two (which I am aware of) (equivalent) definitions of CW-complexes:

- You can define them as a Hausdorff space with a partition in cells and attaching maps. The definition you are speaking about. [See for example Lee's Introduction to topological manifolds, 2nd edition]
- You can also define them inductively which could appeal more to your geometric intuition [See Hatcher's book for example].

The equivalence of the definitions is proved in Chapter five of Lee's book.

Hope this helps. If you want more information don't hesitate to ask!